# Linux du command without traversing mounted file systems

Tags: linux, du, mount-point

If the wording of the question is wrong, please let me know. It might explain why I can’t find an answer.

I want to find the usage on my main disk using a command like:

```
du -sh /*
```

The problem is that I have a number of mount points at the root level, and I would like `du` to skip these.

I thought the `-x` option was supposed to do this, but either I misunderstand what it does or I’m using it the wrong way.

How can I apply `du` to only the root disk without traversing the additional mounts?

Thanks

Comment: In other words, are you looking for summary usage of `/bin`, `/etc`, and other folders under `/`, while excluding `/run`, `/proc/`, `/sys`, and so on?

Comment: I also have additional drives mounted at `/data` and `/backup` and so on, but that’s basically correct.

Comment: I think you are using `du` properly, the problem is that `/*` is expanding to include every mount point under `/`, then `du` iterates over each one, which defeats the `-x` usage. The only way to solve this might be with a creative script.

Comment: @jamieguinan What would be wrong with replacing `/*` with `/`? Why would that not fix it and instead require a creative script?

Comment: @DuncanXSimpson `/` would only show the sum total of `/`. He wanted to see the subtotals for non-mounted folders.

Comment: @jamiegunan Oh yeah I wasn't thinking of that. In any case the command they need is `df -h`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is hacky, but it seems to do what you want, from the shell,

```
for d in /*; do egrep " ${d} " /proc/mounts > /dev/null || du -sh ${d}; done
```

Add a `sudo` in front of the `du` if needed.

Comment: Sorry it’s taken me so long to accept this. Your comment above, I think, explains _why_ the `-x` isn’t working, and your answer is a solution. In my own usage, I have modified it as follows: `for i in /*; do if ! mountpoint -q "$i"; then du -sh $i; fi; done;`. Thanks

Comment: You can avoid the for loop: `du -d1 -x` means starting in the current directory, go down to a depth of 1 (so, single level of subdirectories), and also skip directories on different file systems.
My rootfs is an ssd, but also have a zfs raid mounted, and I wanted to do a quick check of what's taking up space on the ssd without wasting time on the hard drives; this works.

Comment: but `-s` conficts with `-d1` what was the original question

Answer (score 70):

`du -x` will not traverse any mount points it encounters. But if it is told to *start* at a mount point then it will do as requested.

Comment: To build on this, if you have a volume mounted in the root directory, `du -shx /*` will scan the volume since you are *starting* on the mounted volume.

Comment: AKA, do not put the star: `du -hx /`